# Погасить или затушить?

Tags: лексика

Контекст: загорелась одежда. Можно ли применить слово "погасить" по отношению к одежде (погасить одежду)? Или лучше "затушить" ("потушить")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, разница тут в небольших оттенках смысла. Так, гасить можно, скажем так, локальное возгорание: спичку, костерок, горящую одежду. А тушить - нечто более глобальное, например, пожар.

Answer (score 0):

Формального запрета нет. В одном из значений (по Кузнецову - вообще в первом, т.е. гланом) гасить синонимично тушить.
*Прекращать горение, свечение; тушить. Г. лампу, свет. Г. пожар.*

Хотя, надо признать, свечу действительно хочется гасить, а пожар скорее тушить. 
Не буду рассуждать почему так, не вижу объективных критериев.